# C# MetroGrid tool forget value after restart visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I use metro modern UI 1.4.0 in visual studio C# 2019.
my problem is with MetroGrid, the value of property **borderstyle** still None , I can change it manually but no affect appears at runtime, after restart visual studio the value of property back to None again.
How to solve this problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: `BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;` is set in the constructor of the Grid Control and the method that sets it is also called by a number of custom properties. You have the source code, though.

Comment: @Jimi , thanks but I need to see the fixedsingle (as example) at design and runtime not just at runtime by adding your code

Comment: My code? As mentioned, most styling properties (those that set the custom styles / themes), call a `SetStyles()` method internally. The first thing this method does is `this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;`. BUT, since the source code is available, you can change that, if you want. Mind that the border adds 2 pixels in width and height, so there's the chance that some custom drawing could be off the hinges at some point.

Comment: You could simply try to set a different border style in the Form Constructor, after `InitializeComponent()` or `OnHandleCreated()` (I don't know whether that control recreates its handle sometimes). See if that's enough.